# Service or property not registered error

Tags: java, linux, azure

Simply when I run this code:

```
Configuration azureConfig = ManagementConfiguration.configure(
    new URI("https://management.core.windows.net/"), 
    "asdasdasd",
    "server.keystore",
    "asdasdasd",
    KeyStoreType.jks
);
ManagementClient client = ManagementService.create(azureConfig);
LocationsListResponse response = client.getLocationsOperations().list();
ArrayList locations = response.getLocations();

for( int i=0; i<locations.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(((LocationsListResponse.Location)locations.get(i)).getDisplayName());
}
```

I get this:

```
00:52:04 [SEVERE] java.lang.RuntimeException: Service or property not registered: com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementClient interface com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementClient
00:52:04 [SEVERE]     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.DefaultBuilder.build(DefaultBuilder.java:197)
00:52:04 [SEVERE]     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration.create(Configuration.java:113)
00:52:04 [SEVERE]     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementService.create(ManagementService.java:46)
00:52:04 [SEVERE]     at {LINE OF CODE THAT CONTAINS ManagementClient client = ManagementService.create(azureConfig);}
```

On internet there's only 1 question about this, about Android and don't has a clear reply... Has someone solved this problem?

I run it under OpenLogic 6.5 (based on CentOS) in a Virtual Machine from Azure with Java 1.8.

**EDIT:** I created a new project and launched it from eclipse. I get the correct results but when I launch it from command line (java -jar test.jar) i receive exactly the same error.

Comment: hi @Jorge were you able to solve this issue I am facing a similar kind of issue.

Could you please help me resolve this.

Thank You.

Comment: @AnkushReddySugureddy Long time ago from this. Don't really remember as I moved away from Azure. Sorry :-/ If I accpeted the answer, it helped me for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced similar issue. Explicitly setting context class loader solved the problem

```
// Get current context class loader
ClassLoader contextLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); 
// Change context classloader to class context loader   
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(AzureManagementServiceDelegate.class.getClassLoader)); 
try { 
     // Call Azure API and reset back the context loader 
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exceptions  
} finally {
 // Reset back class loader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(contextLoader); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @snallami  when am trying to modify the code with this line Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ServiceBusContr‌​act.class.getClassLo‌​ader)) am getting an error saying that expected identifier but class found near ServiceBusContract.class and I see "))" at the end of the line could you please let me know if am missing anything. Thank You for Your help. –