# Connect Azure service bus on Android by Rest API

Tags: java, android, azure

I'm writting an Android App and connect to Azure Service bus - Topic. I write code to connect to existing namespace like this tutorial
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/

```
Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
  "HowToSample",
  "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
  "SAS_key_value",
  ".servicebus.windows.net"
  );

ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
```

But it throw an exception at ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);.
It said "`java.lang.RuntimeException: Service or property not registered:  com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.ServiceBusContract`
I looked up some way to fix it but not ok. So i use REST API to connect same this tutorial
[REST API AZURE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844836/2412534)

It can run and sent message to Azure Service Bus - Topic. Now i want to write a method use to get message from this Topic's Subcription. Use Rest API like that

```
String url = "https://smarthomethesis.servicebus.windows.net/light_1/Subscriptions/LightSubscription/messages/head?timeout=60";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

// Add header
String token = generateSasToken(new URI(uri));

get.setHeader("Authorization", token);
System.out.println("Llamando al post");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

But it can't get message, responseString show

```
"<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>The request is not supported for the supplied api-version ''. TrackingId:d7624c10-4fc9-43d6-b092-880947e3b820_G31,TimeStamp:1/10/2016 3:43:44 PM</Detail></Error>"
```

I don't know why it isn't supported. Can you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your code in Azure Java SDK, the issue was caused by using incorrect `namespace`, `sasKeyName` & `sasKey`. In the reference doc, the namespace `HowToSample` & SAS key `SAS_key_value` were created by the author, that be different from yours.

So you need to replace them with the namespace & SAS key value of your service bus created. You can find them on Azure portal or new portal.

For the Service Bus REST API, try to add the `api-version` in the query string for the `Peek-Lock Message` API, please note the content from the reference doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780771.aspx.

> ## Version and server overview
>
> Following Azure guidelines, REST APIs now support versioning. By default, passing no version indicates current service behavior. Any changes in existing REST APIs require providing an **api-version** value as the query string.
>
> **Version** “2012-03”,“2012-08”,“2013-04”,“2013-07”,“2013-08”,“2013-10”,“2014-01”,“2015-01”